# Why can I compute a mixed model with lme, but not with lmer?

Tags: r, lme4, nlme

I'm attempting to run a mixed model in R with the lme4 package.

```
library(lme4)
m1 <- lmer(rt2 ~ condition + rt1 + condition*rt1 + (1 | subj) , data = df)
```

I get the following error message: "Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations". The error message makes sense because I have 46 observations and 46 participants.

However, I can run the same model with the nlme package without any error message:

```
library(nlme)
m2 <- lme(rt2 ~ condition + rt1 + condition*rt1, data = df, random = ~ 1 | subj)
```

Why can I run the model with nlme but not with lme4? Is it ok to interpret the results from the second model?

My data looks something like this:

```
df <- structure(list(subj = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L), condition = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), rt1 = c(46.8105499999999, 76.370818692028, 59.778292128193, 24.883242857143, 21.226639867672, -21.03400237712, 51.0391505102041, 69.012199029126, 179.014368072932, 46.15812435546, 78.448862797267, 66.473437810945, 108.827163519139, 73.6389999424071, 89.829873737374, 86.251484994273, 88.412976831683, 203.226219871798, 11.293038244384, 115.500764155017, 101.520579909222, 85.912837438554, 163.099186091535, 178.796075376344, 172.592490740741, 151.171400701587,311.318290305009, 124.107150003926, 103.790202412333, 196.283178266371, 82.789046400187, 98.4326761904771, 149.504007586534, 178.81566904762, 101.143787442057, 338.369788946405, 88.04309478022, 156.055273468631, 102.908947097659, 103.923616878268, 237.106966609653, 215.461850843354, 18.017751248898, 224.736390582656, 218.40048947368, 76.260591417598), rt2 = c(35.5943547858769, 121.999683164729, 70.1167870281901, 46.1811456947171, 81.779957179474, 148.111105656111, 149.603506610939, 55.862105226296, 143.207197715373, 34.887128220687, 38.299248863636, 95.2843711396361, 97.0520967833841, 107.832187165775, 91.821258606965, 99.957164922988, 84.3041822023661, 237.325642673231, 26.771263754184, 109.846556878307, 169.615306823133, 86.5665153566119, 305.010019372861, 220.792146257438, 223.790192245031, 158.432720855615, 313.328780519479, 190.188307417046, 116.799351221776, 181.491207732176, 99.9429508950891, 245.527463325564, 307.644367565137, 267.87756818182, 183.903568478261, 295.491853846154, 87.341270500928, 220.234276984125, 185.366267480097, 244.873834818776, 329.992332220494, 298.392818041876, 91.081530603128, 150.335149529625, 328.832859339508, 365.738806305878)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L), class = "data.frame")

   subj condition       rt1       rt2
     1         0  46.81055  35.59435
     2         0  76.37082 121.99968
     3         0  59.77829  70.11679
     4         0  24.88324  46.18115
     5         0  21.22664  81.77996
     6         0 -21.03400 148.11111
```

The variable "condition" is between-subjects.

Comment: I'm not sure why would you add a random effect if your observations are iid for a Gaussian model - perhaps lme4 is more strict than nlme in checking this.  Are the results from m2 the same as from a linear model `m3 <- lm(rt2 ~ condition + rt1 + condition*rt1, data = df)`?

Comment: I am not sure how much the random effects term helps you here, since you are sort of using it as an observation-level random effect, which can be used in `glmer`. Also note that `condition*rt1` = `condition + rt1 + condition:rt1`, with the latter term being the interaction. I don't think you want `condition + rt1 + condition*rt1` unless you are trying to write: `condition + rt1 + condition + rt1 + condition:rt1`